# What could be the answer of this maths puzzle?

Tags: number-sequence, calculation-puzzle

Found this puzzle online. Tried many possible combinations of numbers with multiplication, addition etc. Has anyone ever solved this?

[image]

Comment: Also, the handwriting is ambiguous. Is that 283 or 233 in the top left corner? Is that a 4 or a 5 or a 7 in the ENE octant between 3 and 8?

Comment: Its is 233 and 4. I got the answer. It is (6+9)square + (9)square = 306